# I have uploaded my apk to google play but showing no device is compatible, any

Tags: java, android, build, apk, manifest

I'm trying to upload my apk to google play but I'm having a problem. In the previous version I did not have any problems, but when I go to android studio and load in google play I get the error "Your device is not compatible with this version". Before, it did not happen to me. In google play console, it tells me that no device is compatible. That is very strange.

I put build and manifest:

Build:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my apk"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 23
    versionName "2.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app"
    android:versionCode="20"
    android:versionName="1.5.8" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
              android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Principal"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <meta-data 
                 android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                 android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: what are the extra items you added in this release while compare to previous. means any permission as such

Comment: does this issue shows in your emulator

Comment: I've added <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: Pranav Ashok - 
No, I'm emulating it in my phone and it works perfectly

Comment: I have found the solution !!! It was changing 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4' of the buil by 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'